# Cropping images to box

Tags: crop, adjustbox

Is there any easy way in (Lua)LaTeX to crop an image to a specific bounding box, but only cropping on the one dimension which is too large for the box?

A solution to crop on the height could be the following:

```
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\adjustimage{clip=true, 
             trim=0cm {0.5\height-6cm*\width/\pagewidth} 0cm {0.5\height-6cm*\width/\pagewidth}, 
             keepaspectratio=true, 
             width=\pagewidth}
             {image.jpg}
```

But I would like to crop on the dimension which is larger than the bounding box automatically.

Is there some package I have overlooked? It's kind of hard to believe I am the first wanting to do this?

The use case is a title page, but where I would like to be able to swap the image depending on the document. So in general I do not know the dimensions of the image in advance or the orientation. It has to be determined from LaTeX.

Comment: Instead of `clip=true, trim=...` you can just use `Clip=...` (note the uppercase 'C'). Also `keepaspectratio=true` is only used if `width` and `height` are both used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\newcommand{\fillbox}[3]% #1=width, #2=height, #3=filename
{\bgroup
  \dimen1=#1\relax% store width into register
  \dimen2=#2\relax% store height into register
  \sbox0{\includegraphics[width=#1]{#3}}%
  \ifdim\ht0>\dimen2
    \dimen0=\dimexpr \ht0-\dimen2\relax
    \adjustbox{clip=true,trim=0pt 0.5\dimen0 0pt 0.5\dimen0}{\usebox0}%
  \else
    \sbox0{\includegraphics[height=#2]{#3}}%
    \ifdim\wd0>\dimen1
      \dimen0=\dimexpr \wd0-\dimen1\relax
      \adjustbox{clip=true,trim=0.5\dimen0 0pt 0.5\dimen0 0pt}{\usebox0}%
    \else
      \usebox0
    \fi
  \fi
\egroup}

\begin{document}
\noindent\fillbox{\textwidth}{0.2\textheight}{example-image}
\rule{\textwidth}{0.2\textheight}

\noindent\fillbox{0.4\textwidth}{0.5\textheight}{example-image}%
\rule{0.4\textwidth}{0.5\textheight}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: It works like intended - thank you very much.

Comment: Honestly this deserves more upvotes. Thank you so much!