# How to restrict an image's output to a minipage?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, minipage

I'm trying to create a fancy cover for a document chapter where I want to include a picture that's related to the content, for which I've created a `minipage` environment inside which I placed a `tikzpicture` containing the chapter title, some grey background to simulate some shadow and the image itself. However the image file is not the same size as the `minipage` box and it 'leaks out'.

Is there a parameter or a way to work around this so that I can upscale the image while restricting it to only be printed inside the `minipage` environment? I did find this solution ([Cropping images to box](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/436017/cropping-images-to-box)) but I'm picky replacing the `minipage` so I keep the labels for the chapter.

Here's the code I got so far:

```
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}\geometry{letterpaper, margin=1in}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{minipage}[b][6cm]{\paperwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[fill=gray, xshift=-3cm] (current page.north west) rectangle (\paperwidth, 0cm); %% grey shadow rectangle
        \node[yshift=9cm, opacity=0.5] at (current page.center)
            {\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{nilum}}; %% the image 
        \node[rectangle, rounded corners=8pt, fill=blue] at (1.5,0)
            {\Huge\bfseries\color{red} Chapter one}; %% chapter title
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}\vspace{3em}
\lipsum[1]
```

[image: This is what the output looks like currently]

Comment: Minipage has no cropping ability whatsoever.   Its primary effect here is to reserve 6cm of vertical space inside the text area, with the right side being off the page.  Note that (1.5,0) is positoned relative to the cursor location inside the minipage.

Comment: Note that the tikzpagenodes package will give you access to `(current page text area.north)` etc.